# Как достать три раза по индексу значения из массива?

Tags: javascript

```
const info = {
    title: 'Hello!!!',
    graduatesCount: 2000,
    areYouChampion: true,
    technologies: ['Front', 'Back', 'Devops']
}
let techSelect = document.createElement('select');
let render = document.createElement('option');
render.append(info.technologies);
techSelect.append(render);
document.body.append(techSelect);


let techSelect = document.createElement('select');
let render = document.createElement('option');
render.append(info.technologies);
techSelect.append(render);
document.body.append(techSelect);
```

Comment: Чего куда и по какой очереди?

Comment: Для работы с массивами используют циклы

Comment: Front Back Devops выпадало по очереди!не могу разобраться как сделать

Comment: просто достать три раза по индексу значения из массива

Comment: Добавив 3 раза текст к тегу options, вы решите свою проблему?

Answer (score 1):

> Как достать три раза по индексу значения из массива?

Например вот так...

```js
const info = {
    title: 'Hello!!!',
    graduatesCount: 2000,
    areYouChampion: true,
    technologies: ['Front', 'Back', 'Devops']
}
const techSelect = document.createElement('select');
for (let i = 0; i < info.technologies.length; i++) {
  const render = document.createElement('option');
  render.textContent = info.technologies[i];
  techSelect.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', render);
}
document.body.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', techSelect);
```